# Pycharm: Python Qt code code completion

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pycharm, code-completion

I am a beginner with Qt in Python.

I create simple from using **Qt Designer**.

[image]

What I need - after user click to button, app copy text from edit to label.

I have file `example.ui` from Qt Designer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>308</width>
    <height>143</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>17</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Enter name</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>113</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>85</width>
      <height>27</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Display</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>261</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

How can I use it in my Python code?

I modify code from some tutorial and it works:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("example.ui")[0] 

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_clicked) 

    def pushButton_clicked(self):
        input = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.label_2.setText(input)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

But code completion doesn't work! So it is unusable for me :-(

I'm using **JetBrains Pycharm**.

What is right way to use Qt designer output in python code with working code competition in IDE?

Comment: I am also using Pycharm for Python & PyQT developing, it works fine. When you mean auto-complete doesn't work, can you give some details? The PyQt module auto-complete failed or the UI part failed?

Comment: OK, I got your point. You should not expect auto-complete when using "loadUiType",as "loadUiType" happens at runtime, but auto-complete depends on static analysis, so the correct way is you uses "pyuic" to generate the UI files into a .py file, then in your project, your import it and make use of it, then auto-complete will work

Comment: Example: I want to use *QLabel* with **name="label_2"**. In Pycharm I start writing "labe" and press ctrl+space and get *no suggestions* https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6943408/pyqt_completion_err.png

Comment: Yes, see my last post, make use of the generated file by pyuic, instead of calling "loadUiType", then use setupUi to install the generated python file, in that case, the auto-complete will work fine!

Comment: FYI, as pyuic will output to stdout as default, so you need to redirect the output to a python file, then import it.

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer but surely mentionable: Code completion does not work for dynamic objects. You could of course still use

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.abc)
```

instead of

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.abc)
```

but there won't be any code completion for `self.pushButton.clicked.*`

(This also answers the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28270242/4537483 )

Answer (score 1):

1) generate python code: `pyuic4 -o mygui.py mygui.ui`

2) write code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mygui import Ui_MainWindow

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.abc)

    def abc(self):
        input = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        self.ui.label_2.setText(input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works, but is possible to write `QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.abc)` simpler?